# CentOS 7 Postfix - Dovecot Temporary internal error

Tags: centos, postfix, centos7, dovecot

Server is connecting with outside clients with success.
Autentication with success.
Sending emails with success.

The problem lies in the receiving.
The e-mails arive to the machine but I guess they aren't getting sorted out.

Error in all received emails:

> host mail.example.com[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 451 4.3.0  Temporary internal error (in reply to end of DATA command)

I looked around dovecot config files but I couldn't find the problem.

Where should I look at to fix this issue? What config files from dovecot can I link here for you guys to see?

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Thank you for your inspiring sentence. I feel so good after fixing this, and at the same time so dumb for taking this much time.

Answer (score 4):

Enable logs on /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-logging.conf with something like this

```
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
```

Then set its permissions

```
#chown vmail:dovecot /var/log/dovecot.log
#chmod 660 /var/log/dovecot.log
```

In my case logs were giving out this error:

> Error: mkdir(/var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com/jc/) failed: Permission denied

I created manually the jc directory and have it permissions and ownership.

Then I got this error on logs:

> we're not in group 12(mail), dir owned by 0:12 mode=0775)

I solved the issue with:

```
#chown vmail /var/mail/vhosts/mydomain.com
```

and got that sweet:

> saved mail to INBOX

In logs

Comment: You could also have added dovecot to the mail group.